# How to fix ListView not showing contents of ObservableCollecton which is binded to it's ItemSource

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, mvvm

I am using MVVM pattern in my Xamarin.Forms application. I am trying to fill my page with a list of cards with simple information. For that I am using an ObservableCollection (CardsCollectionViewModel.cs) and objects of the class(CardViewModel) which are stored in the collection.

The Collection is initialized and passed to the MainPage.xaml.cs class. In the MainPage.xaml the collection name is binded to ListView ItemSource and the properties of storing objects are binded to the contents of list.

After the program starts and loads the Cards collections successfull, the page appears to be left empty.

Full project here: https://github.com/InfroLab/barkot/tree/master/Barkot

Here is my card class:
CardViewModel.cs

```cs
    public class CardViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //some code
        public CardViewModel(int id, string company, string barcode, string type, string site)
        {
            //some code
        }

        private int id;
        private string company = "";
        private string barcode = "";
        private string type = "";
        private string site = "";

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Company
        {
            get { return company; }
            set
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("{0}", Company);
                if (company != value)
                {
                    company = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Company");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Barcode
        {
            get { return barcode; }
            set
            {
                if (barcode != value)
                {
                    barcode = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Barcode");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Type
        {
            get { return type; }
            set
            {
                if (type != value)
                {
                    type = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Type");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Site
        {
            get { return site; }
            set
            {
                if (site != value)
                {
                    site = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Site");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my collection class:
CarCollectionViewModel.cs

```cs
public class CardCollectionViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<CardViewModel> Cards { get; set; }
        //some code
        public static void UpdateCards()
        {
            //gettingitems from local db
            Cards = App.Database.GetItems();
        }
        public CardCollectionViewModel()
        {
            Cards = new ObservableCollection<CardViewModel>();
            UpdateCards();
            //some code
        }
    }
```

Here is ListView from MainPage.xaml:

```xml
<ListView SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}" SelectionMode="None">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                            <Frame Margin="10" HeightRequest="148" Padding="10" CornerRadius="5" HasShadow="True" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" InputTransparent="False" >
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Button Text="Edit" Command="{Binding EditCardCommand}" BackgroundColor="#EBEBEB" HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <WebView Source="{Binding Site}" HeightRequest="128" WidthRequest="128" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                        <StackLayout Spacing="5" Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Company}" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#232323" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Barcode}" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#232323" />
                                            <forms:ZXingBarcodeImageView  BarcodeFormat="{Binding Type}" BarcodeValue="{Binding Barcode}" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="200">
                                                <zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
                                                    <zxcm:EncodingOptions Width="200" Height="40" PureBarcode="True"/>
                                                </zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
                                            </forms:ZXingBarcodeImageView>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

I expect to see a loaded list on my page, but the actual content of it is empty.

**SOLUTION:**

```cs
        private ObservableCollection<CardViewModel> cards = new ObservableCollection<CardViewModel>();
        public ObservableCollection<CardViewModel> Cards
        {
            get
            {
                return cards;
            }
            set
            {
                if (cards != value)
                {
                    cards = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Cards");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you update `Cards`

```
Cards = App.Database.GetItems();
```

you are not raising a `PropertyChanged` event because you are using a default getter for Cards

Comment: Thanks! I made and PropertyChnaged called get method and it worked.